# Test Class for Content Document Link trigger

Tags: after-trigger

I have created a trigger functionality on after insert of content document link, trigger functionality is working as expecting.

But when i have written a test class to insert test record for ContentDocumentLink object to get code coverage, the LinkedEntityId is always taking a user id, i want a custom object record id in this place. Because i have a if condition for to check based prefix.

Below is my class and test class.

```
public with sharing class X{ 
    public void y(List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocLinkLst){
        //Load Request Form Keyprfix
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult GetObjkeyPrefix = A__C.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        String StrkeyPrefix = GetObjkeyPrefix.getKeyPrefix();
        List<A__C> ALst  = new List<A__C>();
        system.debug('###contentDocLinkLst::'+contentDocLinkLst);
        for(ContentDocumentLink link: contentDocLinkLst){
            string strparentid = link.LinkedEntityId;
            if(strparentid.substring(0,3) == StrkeyPrefix){
                A__C updrec = new A__C();
                updrec.Id = link.LinkedEntityId;  
                ALst.add(updRec);
            }
        }
        //Updating BIC Result object records
        if(!ALst.isEmpty())
            Update ALst;
     } 
}
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
private class ContentDocumentLinkActionTest{
//Inserting list of A__C object records
        List<A__C> ALst = new List<A__C>();
        A__C br;
        for(integer i=0; i<=5; i++){
            br = new A__C();
            br.BIC_Name__c = bic.Id;
            br.BIC_Question__c = ques.Id;
            br.BIC_Section__c = sec.Id;
            br.Visibility__c=true;
            br.Meets_Standard__c='Yes'; 
            ALst.add(br);
        }
        insert ALst;
        system.assert(ALst[0].id != null, true);  

        //Inserting content document link record
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Penguins',
            PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
            IsMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert contentVersion;   
        List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];
        //create ContentDocumentLink  record 

        ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = ALst[0].id;
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
        cdl.shareType = 'V';
        insert cdl;
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class ContentDocumentLinkAction { 

    // Initialize static booleans to track if this is the first time a specific
    // Trigger Action has been called within the current Execution Context.
    public  static  boolean onBeforeInsert_FirstRun   = true;
    public  static  boolean onBeforeUpdate_FirstRun   = true;
    public  static  boolean onBeforeDelete_FirstRun   = true;
    public  static  boolean onAfterInsert_FirstRun    = true;
    public  static  boolean onAfterUpdate_FirstRun    = true;
    public  static  boolean onAfterDelete_FirstRun    = true;
    public  static  boolean onAfterUndelete_FirstRun  = true;
    public  static UpdateBICResultOnFileUpload updateBICResult = new UpdateBICResultOnFileUpload();
    Public static final string strUpdate = 'Update'; 

    // Instance variables that will hold information about specific runs through
    // the trigger.
    private         integer batchSize                  = 0;
    public          boolean isTriggerContext           {get{return (isTriggerContext == null) ? false : isTriggerContext;} private set;}    // Returns TRUE if the execution context was begun via the Standard UI, ie. NOT Visualforce, API call, etc.

    // Constructor
    public ContentDocumentLinkAction(boolean isTriggerContextParam, integer batchSizeParam) {

        isTriggerContext  = isTriggerContextParam;
        batchSize         = batchSizeParam;
    }

    /**
    * onBeforeInsert() Handler.
    * #Describe the functional logic of this trigger action handler.#
    * @param    newObjects          List of SObjects that are about to be inserted.
    * @return   void
    * @see      #List any service classes referenced by this action handler#
    */
    public void onAfterInsert(List<SObject> newObjects) {
        if(onAfterInsert_FirstRun) {
            // IMPLEMENT "BEFORE INSERT" LOGIC
            // PREVENT RECURSION
            onAfterInsert_FirstRun = false; 
            //Updating BIC result object fields
            updateBICResult.UpdateBICResult(newObjects);        
        } 
    }
}
```

The if condition logic is not at all covering.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Did u try to wrap your test code inside System.runAs() Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; User u = new User(Alias = 'newUser', Email='newuser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='vvvvv23445@tigy.mkuil',Currency__c = 'INR'); System.runAs(u) { //put your test logic here. }

Comment: What is the purpose of the static variable `bicresultId`? What logic creates the list `contentDocLinkLst`? If you debug the input into the function `y()`, what do you see exactly?

Comment: I tried to put a value for this variable from test class, but that is not working for me. This logic we are calling from contentdocumentlink after insert trigger. when i put a log in test class excution. |DEBUG|###contentDocLinkLst::(ContentDocumentLink:{Id=06A1F0000006TDQUA2, LinkedEntityId=0051F000001rRe6QAE, ContentDocumentId=0691F0000005pLkQAI, IsDeleted=false, SystemModstamp=2018-10-10 12:37:28, ShareType=I, Visibility=AllUsers}) this is the debug i got. Here if u observe LinkedEntityId=0051F000001rRe6QAE is user id i am expecting A__c record id here.

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected - the ContentDocument is automatically shared to its owner, the running user. You should *also* see the ContentDocumentLink you insert. Can you edit your trigger code into your question? Are you perhaps using a static Boolean recursion guard?

Comment: Yes i am doing recursive check.

Comment: Please **show your trigger code**. I am fairly confident that the recursion check is the problem.

Comment: I have added recursive code to the question please refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your naive recursion guard, because this trigger **must** execute twice in the course of the test transaction to operate correctly.

```
if(onAfterInsert_FirstRun) {
    // IMPLEMENT "BEFORE INSERT" LOGIC
    // PREVENT RECURSION
    onAfterInsert_FirstRun = false; 
    //Updating BIC result object fields
    updateBICResult.UpdateBICResult(newObjects);        
}
```

This code is executed once when you insert your `ContentDocument` in your test, because the system at that point *automatically* inserts a `ContentDocumentLink` to share the `ContentDocument` to its owner, your test running user. That's the record you're seeing in your debug logs.

Then, when you insert your `ContentDocumentLink` to share the file to the `A__c` record, your trigger code **does not execute**, because `onAfterInsert_FirstRun` is `false` - the trigger already ran on the earlier DML operation.

There are many, many situations in which this simplistic recursion guard will not work. A static `Set` of already-processed records works *better*, but still has some issues. However, it's not clear to me why you need recursion defense on this `after insert` operation at all.

In any case, that's your problem. You need to fix your recursion guard, and your test will probably pass - the code looks good to me. You do need to be writing some assertions to make this a true unit test, however.

Comment: Now i understand, it's a very good discussion. If the recursion is the problem when i am inserting a file under A__c record there it is firing twice one for user another for A__c. There also it should run only once right as per recursion guard, why in test class alone it running only once?

Comment: The trigger is *not* recursing. Your recursion guard is blocking it from running when it should run.

Comment: Yes the problem is with the recursive guard, i changed it then able to cover the test class. Thanks for your valuable time and suggestions.