# Trigger on ContentDocumentLink gets fired for current user in test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, after-trigger, contentversion, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to increase test coverage of an after-trigger on `ContentDocumentLink`. The problem is that the trigger gets fired twice. I found out from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235466/test-class-for-content-document-link-trigger) answer that the trigger fires one extra time because the system automatically inserts a ContentDocumentLink to share the ContentDocument to its owner. Due to this, the running User Id is assigned to `ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId`. This generates error ahead in the trigger. The trigger needs `ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId` to be a Case Id only.

**Trigger Code:**

```js
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert, after update) {
    list<ContentDocumentLink> ContentDocumentLinklist = Trigger.new;
    String ContentDocumentLinklistStr = JSON.serialize(ContentDocumentLinklist[0]);
    CalloutService.postDocuments(ContentDocumentLinklistStr);//This method needs ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId to be a Case Id only
}
```

**Test Class Code:**
I am referring to [this site](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/salesforce-test-class-data-for-contentdocumentlink/) for test class code.

Is there a way by which I can stop the first trigger execution?

How can I make sure in the trigger that the method `CalloutService.postDocuments()` is called only when `ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId` is a Case Id? Please guide. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger code you will have to put a guard above the line `CalloutService.postDocuments(ContentDocumentLinklistStr);` so that it fires only when the `linkedEntityId` is a caseId.

You can write an `if` statement like this.

```
if(ContentDocumentLinklist[0].linkedEntityId.startsWith('500') {
    String ContentDocumentLinklistStr = JSON.serialize(ContentDocumentLinklist[0]);
    CalloutService.postDocuments(ContentDocumentLinklistStr);
}
```

I would recommend that you bulkify the trigger code.